# how to connect to postgres deployed in openshift

Tags: openshift

After long effort , i got PostgresDB deployed to Openshift ..Its up and running , i can see it in the Openshift web shell..I can execute pg commands as well..
How do i connect it from my local machine or from an outside Openshift code? Suppose if i have a web application deployed somewhere else how can i access this DB? 
Or even from local PostgresDB editor , how can i access it? I tried a few URL's; but its not working.I am missing some concepts here i think.. Do i need a service and a route?

Comment: If you only need temporary access, you can use port forwarding. See https://learn.openshift.com/introduction/port-forwarding/ For permanent access it is more complicated and depends on whether cluster allows for exposing services via a NodePort. https://docs.openshift.com/container-platform/3.11/dev_guide/expose_service/expose_internal_ip_nodeport.html Whose cluster is it? You can't use that with OpenShift Online.

Comment: Its a corporate cluster..
can all pods in my project access this without anything?

Comment: Yes, applications running in a project can access other applications in the same project, preferably via the hostname that is registered when a service is created. If you haven't already, perhaps also read https://www.openshift.com/deploying-to-openshift/ for general stuff on working in OpenShift.

Comment: Depending on how the cluster was setup, an application may be able to access applications in other projects of the same cluster as well. If full multi tenant configuration is in place, they will not.

Comment: u can post it as answer.. i am good with it